# Simple program - menu is being displayed only once

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, logic, cumulative-sum

I am trying to keep a track of total amount of bought groceries.

In my program, every time I buy apples, cheese, or bread, the program should continue with displaying the menu again.

But it keeps asking "How many apples?" after the program has already calculated the total for the apples instead of going back to the menu to choose another item.

Perhaps it has something to do with the type of loop I have used.

I am stuck on trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     double BUDGET;
     const double apple= .60;
     const double lb_cheese= 1.60;
     const double loaf_bread = 2.50;

     double total;
     int count;
     char choice;
     double amount_left;

    cout <<"Welcome! What is the budget for your picnic lunch?"<< endl;
    cin>> BUDGET;

    cout<<"Choose one of the following"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"            MENU             \n "<<endl;
    cout<<"A-Apple      B-Cheese        C-Bread"<<endl;
    cout<<" $0.60       $1.50             $2.50       "<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cin>> choice;



   while ((choice != 'Q') && (total <BUDGET)) //Q is the sentinel value to "quit" the  program
 {


    switch(choice)

  {

    case 'A':
    case 'a':

    cout<<"How many apples?";
    cin>> count;
    total+= (count *apple);
    break;



    case 'B':
    case 'b':

    cout<<"How many pounds of cheese ?";
    cin>> count;

    total+= (count* lb_cheese);
    break;



    case 'C':
    case 'c':
    cout<<"How many loafs of bread?";
    cin>> count;
    total+= (count * loaf_bread);
    break;



    default:
    cout<<"The entry you have entered is not valid, please try again."<<endl;
  }




if( total > BUDGET)
    { cout<<"You have exceeded your budget please check your cart.\n\n";
       break;
       }



cout<<"Your total is: $"<<setprecision((2))<<fixed<<total<<endl;
amount_left= BUDGET-total;
cout<<"You have $"<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<amount_left<<" left to spend."<<endl;



 }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Displaying menu is out of the loop:

```
display menu
read option
while (option != quit) {
    do some calculations
}
```

and the menu is therefore displayed only once. You could change it to *infinite loop*:

```
while (true) {
    display menu
    read option

    if (choice == 'Q' || total >= BUDGET)
        break;

    do some calculations
}
```

Also try to avoid writing functions that are longer than 50 lines, place some logic into some different function and just call this function, decompose it to smaller parts, it will be much easier to read and also much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, get the menu in a loop to display it the number of times you desire and also please remember to initialize your variables as good practice.

Double total=0.00 // initialize.